# Replace certain number values and NA's in a column of a data frame

Tags: replace

I am looking at a Supreme Court database.  A column labeled "direction" contains 1's, 2's, 3's, and NA's.  I want to change all the 3's and NA's to blanks, but have tried all the solutions I can find (including "R for Dummies") to no avail.

I tried this: `justice = filter(justice, direction != "3"| na.rm = TRUE)`.  After that, I got nuthin'...

Comment: please add more details to your question and choose appropriate tags for the language and database you are using